# How To Call procedure by pointer in RPGLE

Tags: rpgle

I use callback in the service module. The pointer of the callback function I want to pass as procedure parameter.

How I could to call the my callback function in the service module?

psevdocode:

main code:

```
 dcl-pr Proc2;
   ptr pointer;      
 end-pr;

 dcl-s ptr inz(%Addr(Proc1))

 Proc2( ptr);

 dcl-proc Proc1;
 dcl-pi *n;
    parm1 char(123);
 end-pi;
   ...     
 end-proc Proc1;
```

Service programm

```
 dcl-proc Proc2;
 dcl-pi *n;
   ptr pointer;
 end-pi;

      dcl-s param char(123) inz('xxxaaaqqq') 

     *ptr( param ); // call callback

 end-proc Proc2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%PADDR() (Get Procedure Address) built in function
PROCPTR keyword (in fixed format d-specs)
POINTER(*PROC) (in free format d-specs)

```
dcl-pr Proc2;
   ptr pointer(*PROC);
end-pr;

Proc2( %paddr(Proc1));

dcl-proc Proc1;
dcl-pi *n *IND;
   parm1 char(123);
   parm2 int(10);
end-pi;
  ...     
end-proc Proc1;
```

*SRVPGM

```
 dcl-proc Proc2;
 dcl-pi *n;
   ptr pointer(*PROC)
 end-pi;

 //defined prototype for callback
 // as EXTernal PROCedure pointed to by ptr
 dcl-pr callback extproc(ptr) *IND;
   cbParm  char(123);
   cbParm2 int(10);
 end-pr;

     dcl-s param char(123) inz('xxxaaaqqq') 
     dcl-s myInt int(10);
     dcl-s success ind;

     success = callback( param:myInt ); // call callback

 end-proc Proc2;
```

Comment: Show us how to add parms and I'll be impressed.  You've succeeded in passing the a program name to procedure by address.

Comment: @danny117, add a parm?  Just add the parm, the callback already has one as does Proc2...

Comment: The parm is the address of the callback.  It'd be impressive if it had some data that made it useful.  For example a success fail parm   callback(param:success);

Comment: @danny117, there's nothing special about additional parms or even a return value...just include them in the PR & PI

Comment: @danny117, also the parm in callback(parm) isn't an address, but data that the callback assuredly does something with.